# Prevent unwanted url on centos server

Tags: apache, centos

Someone attacking my site by sending thousands of requests which are not on my site. Example there is a page on my site like:

www.example.com/page-foods

Attacker tries the links like;

www.example.com/page-foodsgdg

www.example.com/page-foodygmnj

I use cloudflare but when I close "I am under attack mode" server down again.
Is there any tool which learn all of my site urls and prevent unwanted url's request?

My site is drupal6. Serves system is centos5 and apache web server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) to automatically block IPs of unwanted bots.